# Xamarin Android doesn't load AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-manifest

I have a location service which I use to get the current location of the device.

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="Muelleimer_3.Muelleimer_3" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application android:label="Muelleimer_3" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="Muelleimer_3.Muelleimer_3.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And my usage code:

```
LocationManager locMgr;
locMgr = GetSystemService(LocationService) as LocationManager;

locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates("gps", 2000, 1, this);
```

I get an error at `locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates("gps", 2000, 1, this);` with the error message:
`"gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.`

I think my AndroidManifest.xml is not properly loaded and processed by the Visual Studio Builder.

Is there a place to check where Visual Studio/Xamarin looks for the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: What API level are you testing on? Because with Marshmallow(+) you have to also request runtime permissions : https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Comment: I am using API Level 27.

Comment: You need to request runtime permissions